# Nodejs passport authentication hanging

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm following a nodejs book here: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mean-web-development

All is going smoothly until I try and log in using the passport module. It just hangs with no errors. I have tried other solutions I've found on SO such as re-ordering the middleware, but I think they might be for different versions of Express, as some of the syntax looks slightly different (and doesn't work). Here are the relevant parts. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Package.json:

```
{
"name": "MEAN",
"version": "0.0.3",
"description": "First mean app",
"dependencies": {
  "express":            "~4.8.8",
  "morgan":             "~1.3.0",
  "compression":        "~1.0.11",
  "body-parser":        "~1.8.0",
  "method-override":    "~2.2.0",
  "express-session":    "~1.7.6",
  "ejs":                "~1.0.0",
  "connect-flash":      "~0.1.1",
  "mongoose":           "~3.8.15",
  "passport":           "~0.2.1",
  "passport-local":     "~1.0.0"
}
}
```

express.js:

```
module.exports = function(){
var app = express();



if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    app.use(compress());
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use(session({
   saveUnitialized: true,
   resave: true,
   secret: config.sessionSecret
}));


app.set('views', './app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
require('../app/routes/users.server.routes.js')(app);

app.use(express.static('./public'));

return app;
};
```

passport.js

```
module.exports = function(){

var User = mongoose.model('User');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
   User.findOne({
       _id: id
   }, '-password -salt'), function(err, user){
       done(err, user);
   }; 
});

require('./strategies/local.js')();
};
```

the routing:

```
 app.route('/signin')
    .get(users.renderSignin)
    .post(passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/signin',
        failureFlash: true
    }));
```

Edit: it seems to be the passport.deserializeUser function where things break

Comment: hanging the response generally means, you are not handling error or done cases somewhere and so the relevant callbacks are not called. Finally, something has to be written to response else the request keeps waiting here. Put "console.log" statements in your code and check where is the flow broken.

Comment: Adding console.log(user); to the end of the local.js strategy logs the correct user info. Trying other places...

Comment: it seems to be the passport.deserializeUser function where things break. I've checked the guide and it seems the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've gone to the passport docs, and pasted in the code from there, and it seems to work. So... any idea why the MEAN book example isn't working?

Code that worked:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
     done(err, user);
   });
 });
```

Comment: In your deserialize handler, `id` is probably a `string`. In that case, `User.findOne({_id: someString})` will *not* match the document `{_id: someObjectId}`. However, `user.findById` casts `ObjectId`-like strings, so the query will look like this: `User.findOne({_id: someObjectId})`